# IIS website slow on first hit

Tags: iis, iis-8

I have a php website hosted on IIS.
App pool idle timeout is set to 0.
Recycling is set to 3am daily.

After some time of inactivity (0 users on the website) First hit is very slow. (10-15 secods) vs normal 2 seconds.

I looked at the network tab in chrome and it shows that it spends most of the time on "Content Download" of js and css files (~500-600kb)

So, I'm wondering if there's a problem with static files, but not sure.

Comment: Could you please share the output of your website using https://gtmetrix.com/ or https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/  it will show exact reason.

Answer (score 1):

Because the site starts. And when it starts, it needs to compile all the code.

I would be a lot more concerned with "vs normal 2 seconds" (which is ridiculously slow and indicates very bad programming - pages should be served in WAY less than a second) than with the obvious wrong configuration of not keeping the website hot (i.e. loaded and ready to serve).

Comment: I appreciate your response, but I don't see how this answers my original question. How do I know if it recompiles every time? Why does it only happen after 20-30 minutes of inactivity?